# Would a Timer (Threading) finish execute his task before the waiting period for the task re-execution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Just wondering if a Timer (Threading) will finish execute his task before the waiting period for the task re-execution ?

Comment: You can test it easely !!!

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - yes.  
`System.Threading.Timer` - no.  
`System.Timers.Timer` - no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Remarks in [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because
>   it is called on ThreadPool threads. The callback can be executed
>   simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is
>   less than the time required to execute the callback, or if all thread
>   pool threads are in use and the callback is queued multiple times.

So for System.Threading.Timer the answer is No.

Comment: So if i understand correctly.. the first callback will happen on a thread and the second, etc. will happen on different ones ?

Comment: @Rushino Potentially.  They involve separate items in the thread pool, so they may or may not be handled by the same physical thread.

Comment: Not necessarily. It might by the same [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) thread when the callback method finishes before it is called the next time.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Of course a callback method can't be called a second time on a particular thread when it is still executing on the same thread. When the timer ticks while execution of the callback is still in process, the callback is simply executed on another thread. When execution of the callback constantly takes longer than the timer interval, the callback will be executed on ever new threads. Sooner or later you will run out of available threads then.

Answer (score 4):

As @Clemens said, `System.Threading.Timer` just keeps on ticking!

If you want to prevent reentrancy, you can use a `Monitor`, or just a flag like this:

```
int _TimerLock = 0;

void TimerTickSafe( object state )
{
    if ( Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref _TimerLock, 1, 0 ) != 0 ) return;
    try
    {
        TimerTick();
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange( ref _TimerLock, 0 );
    }
}
```

If the timer ticks again while the previous tick is still running, the new tick will be silently ignored.